# differentiate and nest function with template return type

Tags: c++, templates, return-type

#### What I want:

I have an issue with using 'nested'(?) templates as return type for my functions. The function declaration should look something like this:

```cpp
// ### Generate.hpp
// return the template type
// input type is the same for all versions of generate()
template <typename T> T generate(Input in);
```

A few inline definitions for base types like `int`, `bool` are provided.

```cpp
// ### Generate.hpp
template <> inline int generate<int>(Input in) {/*...*/}
```

Others ( e.g. custom classes) can be implemented separately.

```cpp
// ### Custom_Class.hpp
#include "Generate.hpp" // can now make use of template

// ### Custom_Class.cpp
template <> custom::Class generate<custom::Class>(Input in) {/*...*/}
```

#### What's the issue

The issue arises when I want to use the function like this:

```cpp
std::vector<int> x = generate<std::vector<int>>(...);
```

I would need to define something like this:

```cpp
template <typename U> std::vector<U> generate(Input input); // differentiating via return type?
```

and the compiler (g++) won't let this fly.

```
error: call of overloaded ‘generate<std::vector<int>>(Input in)’ is ambiguous
```

#### Possible cause and solution.

C++ can't differentiate functions with only the return type. I would prefer functions with the form `OutputType func(InputType input)` over `func (InputType input, OutputType& output)`, but I'm aware that I can solve this specific scenario in the latter for. There i could regularly overload `generate()` for stl container classes and such, which would enable the compile to differentiate.

The question finally boils down to if there is any template magic I can invoke to get what I originally wanted.

Thank you for your help.

#### Edit 1: more details on the use case

The specific use-case here is a function to further process tokens generated by a lexer.

```cpp
template <typename T> std::pair<size_t, std::optional<T>> parse_tokens(const std::vector<Token>& tokens, size_t start = 0);
```

The functions gets a vector of Tokens (and a start offset) and must attempt to parse the beginning of the token sequenze into an object ot type `T`. That object (alongside the nuber of tokens parsed) is than to be returned.

The ideas that if it is 'known' that after the tokens from `def [int] some_data =` are followed by a list of ints, the functions could be called like `res = parse_tokens<std::vector<int>>(tokens, list_starts_here)`. Having `res.second` for the optional value and `res.first` as the ammount of parsed tokens, needed to advance the parser index.

#### Edit2: Solution thanks to @Artyer

I needed a bit of fidling to make it work with the container class (`generate<T>::generate()` must be used, not just `generate<T>()`, otherwise the compiler can't deal with it). I haven't implemented this solution yet (only did some quick tests), but I'm confident that it can do what I want, how I want it. It should extend well and I can even have the desired functional syntax.

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct generator;

template <typename T> T generate(std::string in) {
    return generator<T>::generate(in);
}

template <>
struct generator<int> {
    static int generate(std::string in) { return std::stoi(in); }
};

template <typename T>
struct generator<std::optional<T>> {
    static std::optional<T> generate(std::string in) 
    { 
        if (in == "nil") 
            return std::nullopt;
        else
            return generator<T>::generate(in);
    }
};
```

Thanks, again.

Comment: What's `Input`? If you know `U` from `Input`, maybe you can do something.

Comment: I assume you want vectors of different types? Perhaps specialization isn't the right solution? Perhaps overloading would be better? And it would really help to know what the "input" really is, since as @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica says it could be used as well.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica In this use-call all versions of the functions will use the same input types. The only thing telling the calls appart would be the `<T>` part between the generic function name and the brackets with the arguments. But yes, if that were the case on could use for example function overloading to solve this.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, I want tu use vectors (and other STL container classes) for all generic types. (Also, I edited the question to make it clearer what I want to do with the function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use partial specialization. Since functions can't be partially specialized, switch to a class template:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct generator;

template <typename T> T generate(Input in) {
    return generator<T>::generate(in);
}

template <>
struct generator<int> {
    static int generate(Input in) { /*...*/ }
};

template <typename T>
struct generator<std::vector<T>> {
    static std::vector<T> generate(Input in) { /*...*/ }
};

// ### Custom_Class.hpp
template <>
struct generator<CustomClass> {
    static CustomClass generate(Input in);
};

// ### Custom_Class.cpp
CustomClass generator<CustomClass>::generate(Input in) {
    return {};
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. At first glance i wasn't sure if I wanted to take the 'detour' trough object type definitions, but this seems to work very well. Also: the key word '*partial* specialization' was helpfull. Being aware of that specific template feature, and that it isn't supported for functions in normal c++, made it also cleare to me why my attempts didn't work.